# What is the parameter's format for SoftLayer_Ticket::addScheduledAutoClose API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to auto close SoftLayer tickets using the auto close api. The SLDN reference says the parameter for that function is a string representation of time, but doesn't mention any format

**activationTime    - string - String representation of a time*

Could you please specify in what date format the string should be passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to set auto close for tickets, the method is outdated. Only employees can set auto close for tickets.

Comment: We have a huge queue of tickets that needs auto close. Can SL employees do it using the private api's ? If so what the best way to make this request?

Comment: You can send an update directly in the ticket requesting the close